# the area of a square is equal to twice the squares's perimeter. Find the length of one side of the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The area of a square is equal to twice the square's perimeter. Find the length of one side of the square.

Don't know how to do this or even where to start to solve this problem.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: If $s$ is the side-length of the square, the area is $s^2$ and the perimeter is $4s$.

Answer (score 5):

A: area

P: perimeter

x: length of side

$$A = 2\times P$$

$$\underbrace{x^2}_{A} = 2(\underbrace{4x}_{P}) = 8x$$

Now you've got a quadratic equation you can easily solve for side length (requiring $x >0$).

$$x^2 = 8x \iff x^2 - 8x = 0 \iff x(x - 8) = 0 \implies x = 0\;\;\text{or}\;\;\bf x = 8$$

Answer (score 0):

Let a be the side of a square 
Now Area $A = a^2$

and Perimeter $P = 4a$

we know  $A=2P$

Putting the values of A and P respectively we get,

$$\begin{align*}
a^2 & {} = 2*4a \\
a^2-8a & {} = 0 \\
a(a-8) & {} = 0 \\
\end{align*}$$

$a=8$ as a cannot be equal to zero (which is the other root)

Hence side is 8 units.

Answer (score 0):

Senseless question: Since the dimension of the area is some_unit$^2$, the perimeter's dimension is some_unit.

Michael

Answer (score -1):

If the length of any one side of the square is x, then the area is x2, and the perimeter is 4x. If the area is twice the perimeter, x2 = 2(4x), and x2 − 8x= 0. By factoring, we see this equation is equivalent to x(x − 8) = 0, which has solutions 0 and 8. The length cannot be 0, so it must be 8 units.

Comment: As is stands, you answer is virtually unintelligible.  For example, is `x2` supposed to represent $x^2$?    It is in desperate need of some MathJax formatting...